# Get two time from a sentence in a string

Tags: php, regex, datetime, preg-match

I have a string with a sentence that has two hh:mm format time and i need to get only the time i tried with preg_match but with no success. The problem is that in the string is also a standard number for the days but i only need the time this is what i have tried:

```
$string = 'Our store is open 7 days a week from 11:00h in the morning until 20:00h in the evening. You can contact us for more information';

preg_match('#([0-9,]+).*?([0-9,]+)#', $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1], $matches[2]);
```

This is the result i got:

```
string(1) "7" string(2) "04"
```

As you can see it gets the number 7 from the days and only 04 from the time.

Comment: `11:00h` does not match `[0-9,]+`…!?

Comment: ah i see the [0-9,]+ must be [0-9:0-9]+this is my first time really using regex

Comment: I'd recommend something like http://regex101.com to play around with your regex until you get it right…

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$string = 'Our store is open 7 days a week from 11:00h in the morning until 20:00h in the evening. You can contact us for more information';
preg_match_all('/[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}[h]/', $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```